# How to download a file from AWS S3 with version in Command line?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an AWS S3 bucket with versioning and created a file with multiple versions. Is there any way I could download a file with a particular version using command line or API?

Answer (score 23):

To list out a particular file version use below command and you will get ObjectVersionId

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket bucketname --prefix  folder/test/default.json --output json

ObjectVersionId:"Cu9ksraX_OOpbAtobdlYuNPCoJFY4N3S"

aws s3api get-object --bucket bucketname --key folder/test/default.json D:/verions/default.json --version-id Cu9ksraX_OOpbAtobdlYuNPCoJFY4N3S
```

Answer (score 12):

Via [command line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html):

`aws s3api get-object --version-id ...`

To first get a list of the available versions:

`aws s3api list-object-versions ...`

There are similar methods in the respective [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/).

Comment: Hi mbaird, thanks for the reply. I could list the versions of an objects, but could not able to download object with version id. I used the following command: ' aws s3api get-object --bucket <bucket-name>  --version-id <version-id>' I found --key option in the documentation. Is it mandatory to mention --key in the command. How to get --key value?

Comment: Key is the directory+filename. It's the name you gave the file when you uploaded it.

Comment: Hi mbaird,
The following command is working. Thanks for your support. 

#aws s3api get-object --bucket <bucket-name> --key dir/filename --version-id <version-id>  <output-file>

Comment: Is it possible to give the version of the 'aws s3api' in the command?
Like below, 
aws s3api  --version 1.0 get-object --version-id

Comment: Got it to work for 1 file. How should we tweak the Key and Outfile parameters to download the contents of an entire bucket in one shot? I tried * and *.* but no dice.

Answer (score -4):

AWS has several high-level `s3` commands; aws s3 cp, aws s3 ls, aws s3 mv, aws s3 rm, and sync. You can use the `aws s3 cp` like you would a copy source to destination.

`aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET-NAME/PATH/FILE.EXTENTION (LOCAL_PATH/)FILE.EXTENTION`

Comment: The request was to download a file with a specific version, there is no mention of the version in your answer.